# How can I select an option of select2 selectbox with jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I try to select `bird` of my selectbox with jquery. But it keeps to be `cat`, no matter what I do:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();
   $(".select2").val('bird');
      $('.select2').find('option[value="bird"]').prop('selected', true); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2"  style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: try $('.select2').find('option[value="bird"]').prop('selected', true).change()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger the `change` event after setting the value as follows:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();
   $(".select2").val('bird').trigger("change");
      
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2"  style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();
   $(".select2").val('bird');
      $('.select2').find('option[value="bird"]').prop('selected', true).change(); 
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2"  style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option value="bird">Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select2 respects your initial `selected` property if added to an option. I'm not sure if this applies to your case, but it's probably the most semantic solution.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".select2").select2();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <select class=" form-control select2"  style="width: 100%;">
    <option value="cat">Cat</option>
    <option value="dog">Dog</option>
    <option selected value="bird">Bird</option>
  </select>
</div>
```